# usb drives not recognized in Xubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: usb

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad with the following kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux procida 4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 12 13:48:03 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Until recently, I could read without any problem any usb drive (stick, external hdd), but suddenly it stopped recognizing them.
Any of those drives (sticks, external hdds) can be perfectly mounted and read on my iMac desktop, so it doesn't seem to be a problem related with the drives. Also, when I plug in the external hdd to the Thinkpad, the light goes on.

I've followed many threads, but they won't solve my problem.

Here it is the output of some commands, in case anyone out there can help me solve the problem.

`sudo fdisk -l` (whether before or after plugging in the usb drive):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x341f9458

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 960659455 960657408 458,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       960659456 976773167  16113712   7,7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       960661504 976773119  16111616   7,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

~ : lsblk (whether before or after plugging in the usb drive):

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 458,1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   7,7G  0 part [SWAP]
```

The "Disk" utility also shows only sda1, sda2, and sda5.

```
~ : lsusb (whether before, or after)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:7036 Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:012d Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1199:a001 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:021e Apple, Inc. Aluminum Mini Keyboard (ISO)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:1005 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 09da:0006 A4Tech Co., Ltd. Optical Mouse WOP-35 / Trust 450L Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo dmesg -c` (to clear messages)

And, after plugging any usb drive and waiting for 30 sec, dmesg won't 
show anything.

I've also formatted the external hdd, but this won't help, either.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think this is a **kernel related bug**. I guess you are running **kernel 4.4.0-43** of Linux? I had the exact same problem as you and once reverted back to 4.4.0-34, my USB drives are now working perfectly fine again. I haven't checked yet if that bug has already been reported or not. Has anyone done so?